# How to change tab name and favicon in EasyTabs?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am currently using EasyTabs for C#, and it's working fine but I need to be able to at least change the title of the tab from my application, and I can't seem to find anything that will let me do that so far. I'm talking about changing the tab name not the entire form name just the tab names at the top of the screen.

so I need to be able to take a variable from `Form1` and change the tab name, again not all the tabs, but specific tabs that get opened, depending on the page, the variable will be different and each tab needs to be named respectively, just as it would if you were going to different sites in different tabs in chrome.

I have looked at all possible stack overflow questions that already exist and none have really helped, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated, and at this point, I would be happy with even only have tab names and not being able to change the favicon, but both would be amazing.

AppContainer.cs

```
using System;
using EasyTabs;

public partial class AppContainer : TitleBarTabs
{
    public AppContainer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AeroPeekEnabled = true;
        TabRenderer = new ChromeTabRenderer(this);
        Icon = Properties.Resources.icon;
        Text = "Example";
    }

    public override TitleBarTab CreateTab()
    {
         return new TitleBarTab(this)
        {
            Content = new Form1
            {
                Text = "New Tab"
            }
        };
     }

    private void AppContainer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using EasyTabs;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    protected TitleBarTabs ParentTabs
    {
        get
        {
            return (ParentForm as TitleBarTabs);
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EasyTabs;

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        AppContainer container = new AppContainer();

        container.Tabs.Add(
                new TitleBarTab(container)
                {
                    Content = new Form1
                    {
                        Text = "New Tab"
                    }
                }
            );

        container.SelectedTabIndex = 0;
        TitleBarTabsApplicationContext applicationContext = new TitleBarTabsApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.Start(container);
        Application.Run(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the answer before on github a while back, you can change the tab name using `ParentTabs.SelectedTab.Caption = e.Title;`
I'm not entirely sure where "ParentTabs" was supposed to be located though, if you figure it out please update us

Edit; Sorry for the vague answer. In order to have the ParentTabs variable, you need this code:

```
protected TitleBarTabs ParentTabs
   {
       get
       {
           return (ParentForm as TitleBarTabs);
       }
   }
```

You will also need to invoke a new action and Redraw the tabs, using `ParentTabs.RedrawTabs();`

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to show a favecon and have a title show then use the following

Favecon Code:

```
    private void WebUI_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _ = this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            URLSearch.Text = e.Address;
            {
                Uri url = new Uri("https://" + new Uri(WebUI.Address).Host + "/favicon.ico");
                try
                {
                    Icon img = new Icon(new System.IO.MemoryStream(new
                    WebClient().DownloadData(url)));
                    this.Icon = img;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    this.Icon = Properties.Resources.tempIcon;
                    //change tempIcon to your desired icon, extension is .ico 
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

and this is for your Title Code:

```
    private void WebUI_TitleChanged(object sender, TitleChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            FindForm().Text = e.Title;
        });
    }
```

and for all of this to work then you need to use the AddressChanged and TitleChanged Event in your main form like so

```
        WebUI.AddressChanged += WebUI_AddressChanged;
        WebUI.TitleChanged += WebUI_TitleChanged;
```

and that should wrap things up, i hope this helped you.